# Append bash parameters and pass forward to other script

Tags: bash, apache, shell

I need to pass further original parameters and also I want to add some others. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
params="-D FOREGROUND"
params+=" -c Include conf/dev.conf"

/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl $params "$@"
```

This code above don't work as expected if `params` contains of two or more parameters, it treated as one parameter.

Comment: I bit edited my question. `params` treated as a single parameter

Comment: In example above I want `params` be treated as two parameters + some $@ parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in your example should work if the following command is valid when executed at the command line written exactly like this :

```
/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl -D FOREGROUND -c Include conf/dev.conf "$@"
```

A quick web search leads me to think that what you want is this (notice the additional double quotes) :

```
/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl -D FOREGROUND -c "Include conf/dev.conf" "$@"
```

Here is how to achieve that simply and reliably with arrays, in a way that sidesteps "quoting inside quotes" issues:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a params=()
params+=(-D FOREGROUND)
params+=(-c "Include conf/dev.conf")

/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl "${params[@]}" "$@"
```

The `params` array contains 4 strings (`"-D"`, `"FOREGROUND"`, `"-c"` and `"Include conf/dev/conf"`).  The array expansion (`"${params[@]}"`, note that the double quotes are important here) expands them to these 4 strings, as if you had written them with double quotes around them (i.e. without further word splitting).

Using arrays with this kind of expansion is a flexible and reliable to way to build commands and then execute them with a simple expansion.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is the space in the parameter "-c Include conf/dev.conf" then you could just use a backspace to preserve the space character:
params+="-c Include\ conf/dev.conf"